# How can modal dialog wait, if event dispatching thread is not paused?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, modal-dialog

In an example below, the modal dialog is opened inside event dispatching thread. Since dialog is modal, method `setVisible()` is not return until it is closed.

One may suspect this is causing event dispatching thread paused, but it is wrong, since button is operating.

Hence, `setVisible()` method is not blocking the thread.

The question is: is it possible to show modal dialog without blocking a procedure?

```
package tests.javax.swing;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Try_JDialog_Modality2 {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Try_JDialog_Modality2.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                AbstractAction popupAction = new AbstractAction("popup") {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "popup");
                    }

                };

                JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame)null, true);
                dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                dialog.add(new JButton(popupAction));

                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                dialog.setVisible(true);

                log.debug("After set visible");



            }
        });


    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I can do the same with the following snippet:

```
//dialog.setVisible(true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
            }).start();

            log.debug("After set visible");
```

Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 3):

Your question:

> The question is: is it possible to show modal dialog without blocking a procedure?

Yes, call the method **before** displaying the modal dialog. For certain things this might be best accomplished using a call-back type of set up, such as by using a PropertyChangeListener or other type of listener. If it is set up and called prior to visualizing the modal dialog, it should work.

As to the **how** portion of your question, I believe that it blocks input to the other windows but does not stop the Swing event thread. It does stop program flow from the calling code though, perhaps via a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`. Best for you to peek at the Swing source code for the details.

---

**Edit** 
Regarding your update, **never** do this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}).start();
```

as you are now guaranteeing to start the dialog **off** of the Swing event thread.

Comment: If it does not stop event thread, then why is it obligatory to stop procedure with `setVisible()`? It is possible to run `setVisible()` from separate thread, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

`dialog.setVisible(true);` shall be run on AWT Dispatcher thread. So you shall do it other way around.

```
public buttonPressed_OpenDialog_and_doTask(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* my worker background task */
            dialog.dispose(); // at the end of task call this
        }
        }).start();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    // we will continue when worker thread finishes
}
```

Note that even when you block on AWT event dispatcher thread (by method setVisible()). The AWT event dispatcher thread is still running somehow - so all AWT notifications are working like usual. See [doc dialog.setVisible()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)

Note that all is ok even in case that background task would be to fast and it would call `dialog.dispose()` before `dialog.setVisible(true)` is called in previous thread. Luckily `dialog.dispose()` politely waits till dialog gets visible.